# How do I make an automatic calculation between dates with events en the GUI?

Tags: java, date, calendar

The program I am creating is a hotel reservation system. I need to calculate the number of days and calculate the cost (cost = amount of days * price per day) when selecting a check in date (jdatachooser) and a check out date (jdatachooser). And place the result in a textbox. ALL would have to be done automatically when selecting the dates.

For other calculations use "Document Listener" but for this I do not know how. I investigated "Input Method Text Changed" but I do not know how to use it. I hope you can help me. From already thank you very much.

In the code of the calculation I do not have problems, here I leave it by the doubts:

```
void Calc(){    
        Calendar cal;
        int d,m,y;
        Date date_checkin, date_checkout;
        cal = dchooser_date_checkin.getCalendar();
        d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900;

        date_checkin = new Date(y,m,d);

        cal = dchooser_date_checkout.getCalendar();
        d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900;

        date_checkout = new Date(y,m,d);

        long diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert((date_checkout.getTime() - date_checkin.getTime()), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        txt_cost.setText(Long.toString(diff*priceperday)); 
    }
```

Comment: (A) You should change your title to clarify that calculating days is not your issue (a duplicate of *many* other Questions, sure way to earn down-votes), but that how to respond to events in the GUI is your issue. (B) Calendar and Date classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: You have a bug in your conversion.  If you have daylight savings time, then there will be a 23-hour day once a year.  If your period spans this day, then converting the difference in milliseconds to a number of days will round the wrong way and give you an answer that's one day too small.

Comment: How should I do it? And... the automatic calculation through an event in the GUI?

Comment: Use the Java 8 `LocalDate` class.  It has a static method `of` for making a `LocalDate` from day, month and year; and a method `until` for calculating the difference between two `LocalDate` dates.  That gives you a `Period` which has a `getDays` method.

Comment: And if you want to convert a `Calendar` to a `LocalDate`, you can use the `Calendar` class's `toInstant` method  and the `LocalDateTime` class's `ofInstant` method and `toLocalDate` method.

Comment: But how should you use these methods to perform the automatic calculation? I dont understand.